# Set a dynamic meta title on Node with MetaTag module installed

Tags: meta-tags, 10

I've got one specific node where I need to dynamically set the meta title. The logic to determine the correct title is too involved to express in tokens; I need to do it in code.

It seems that I should be able to override the title using the `hook_preprocess_html`; I get the current title, and replace it with the proper title.

After I set the title here though, the Metatag module (8.x-1.26) waltzes in, and replaces my meticulously assembled title by its own fairly generic pattern generated title.
I suppose I could try using the same hooks that Metatag uses to try to outsmart it, but that seems like a fragile approach.

Is there a better way, maybe through Metatag itself?

Comment: you can get hint from here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/317227/add-taxonomy-term-assignment-to-meta-tag/317241#317241 check this hook custom_module_metatags_alter mentioned here

Comment: @mini: turns out using this hook was making things unnecessarily hard for myself: why overwrite the rendered title, if I can just overwrite the token it's based on?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in my case turned out to be to simply override the value of the 'current-page:title' token. This is the token I used in my metatags pattern, and could be easily overriden in hook_tokens_alter.

Other solutions I tried which worked to some degree:

- Using hook_metatags_alter to override the metatags
- Hijacking the _title_callback on the entity.node.canonincal route